# Java list streams function with throttle

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

It is normally used to create stream with mapper function like `itemList.stream().map(item -> someFunction(item)).toList()`. However, if `itemList` is too large in size and `someFunction` is time consuming, e.g. calling API or I/O, it will generate spike in memory usage and thus get killed by kubernetes controller.

Is there a way to thorttle the stream mapper function invocation? Or just execute it in a sequential way with for-loop?

Comment: It's called [_throttle_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throttle). A throttled stream best runs in its own thread, as you want to intermittently take a next step. Like doing a `Thread.sleep(10L)` in a forEach. You should better use a queue or such.

Answer (score 1):

The Java 8 streams are in fact like a different syntax for loops and iterations, so they run synchronous and immediately.

You can either implement you logic in a different way to ensure a fixed amount of memory usage, or if time based throttling would indeed help you can look into reactive programming libraries like spring reactor or rxjava. They offer asynchronous data streams.